# Image taking too long to upload on Amplify S3 Storage using Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, amplify-flutter

I have a simple app that takes picture of something and uploads it to the Amplify S3 Storage using its flutter library `amplify_storage_s3`. The upload time is about 30s-2mins for a jpeg file that is at most 4MB big. Here is the code I'm using to upload the file.

Is there any way of speeding up this uploading process because that long of a wait time is not acceptable to my client

```
  void _uploadImage () async {
    setState(() {
      isPicLoading = true;      
    });
    final key = new DateTime.now().toString();

    // Save to S3 bucket
    await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
      key: key,
      local: this._image
    );

    setState(() {
      isPicLoading = false;
      uploaded = true;
      analyzing = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: did you find a solutions of this problem , I think its a Amplify service performance issue